# Stream or chunk the huge text value from postgres using python psycopg2 (single row, single column)

Tags: python, postgresql, streaming, psycopg2

I am creating a huge SQL text dynamically using select statement which is more than 1GB. While executing SQL to read the column (one) value (generated SQL), the postgres fails to return the output.

```
SQL Error [54000]: ERROR: out of memory
  Detail: Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 1073741741 bytes by 95 more bytes.
```

The output is just one row, one column i.e. not n number of rows, just one string value which is huge. So, I  cannot use fetchmany or other options of cursor as the data (one column) is not fit. The below is already in palce, but won't help in this case.

```
with self.getConnection() as conn:
                with conn.cursor(name=cur_name) as cursor:
                    cursor.itersize = chunksize
                    cursor.execute(sql)
                    while True:
                        results = cursor.fetchmany(chunksize)
.
.
.
```

I tried to store the column value as large object. i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE lo_sql_data (
    id bigserial not null ,
    valuation_date date NOT NULL,
    dynamic_sql oid NULL,
    CONSTRAINT lo_sql_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

insert into lo_sql_data (valuation_date, dynamic_sql )   
SELECT '2023-08-31'::date,  lo_from_bytea(0, format(
$f$
SELECT <my dynamic query which generates a SQL very big>
$f$
)::bytea)
.
.
```

Above works well with dynamic SQL output value which is smaller, but anything bigger than buffer size throws the above error.

The limitation is a t server side (postgres) and I understand we cannot increase string buffer value.

Is there a way to stream the string value as it gets generated and pass it to client (Python) and later in Python I can merge and make a single string?

Or is there any other way for me to get the value of dynamic sql (which is to be executed later) out of server?

Answer (score 1):

This approach is doomed. You cannot return a string that exceeds 1GB, because that is the hard limit for the size of any data type in PostgreSQL. Also, an SQL statement in excess of 1GB won't get you anywhere, because the limit on a protocol message is also 1GB, so you cannot send a statement that is that large.

Compose more reasonable SQL statements. Perhaps your data model has a problem.